# Как реализовать несколько последовательных ответов(ДА-НЕТ) на вопрос в Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Надо реализовать код, чтобы работал так: бот задает вопрос - пользователь отвечает ДА, НЕТ. Если пользователь отвечает ДА, то вопросов больше нет, но, если НЕТ, то снова задается вопрос ДА, НЕТ. На первый ДА/НЕТ реагирует, а вот на второй нет - все время на команды реагирует первый блок да-нет. Как можно решить этот вопрос? Думал, что может быть, если в лямда функцию передать значение false, то обработчик остановиться и код пойдет дальше, но нет - он полностью перестает обрабатывать любые сообщения, кроме нет-да. Библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI
Вот вариант такой строки. @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message if message.text.upper() == 'YES' or message.text.upper() == 'NO' else False)
Проблема в **def 3_step**

```
@bot.message_handler(func = lambda c: True, commands=['komanda'])
def 1_step(message):
    'тут код продолжается'
    for i in values:
        spisok.append(i)
    'тут код продолжается'
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, 2_step)

def 2_step(message):
     'тут код продолжается'
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, 3_step)

def 3_step(message):
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'YES' or 'NO')
    def yes_no(message):
        if message.text == 'YES':
            'выполняется блок'
        elif message.text == 'NO':
            @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'YES' or 'NO') #<- не работает
            def yes_no_2(message):
                if message.text == 'YES':
                    'выполняется код'
                elif message.text == 'NO':
                    'выполняется код'
                else:
                    bot.send_message(id, 'Пиши yes или no')
        else:
            bot.send_message(id, 'Пиши yes или no')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, 4_step)
```

Comment: `@bot.message_handler(commands=['yes_no_2'])` попробуй так

Answer (score 1):

Используйте машину состояний

https://habr.com/ru/post/521946/

https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter3.html

Comment: Стоит оставить более развернутый ответ, а не просто ссылки, ведь ссылки могут стать невалидными

Comment: А есть возможность обойтись без машины состояний? меня 2 блока if не пугают, да и не хочется сейчас разбираться и изучать что это такое, как использовать. меня больше волнует то, что не останавливается обработка команд и не начинается следующий блок. как этот вопрос решить?

Comment: В aiogram вы не можете просто вставить одну функцию внутрь другой, вам нужно делать две отдельные функции и, как вариант, использовать машину состояний. Также можете попробовать записывать ответы пользователей или их порядковые номера в базу данных, но это будет сложнее и потребует больше строк, чем состояния

Answer (score 0):

Для ответов выше, пожалуйста, внимательно читайте вопросы, человек использует телебот, а не аио - телебот имеет встроенную поддержку fsm, метод ниже уже имеет машину состояний.

```
bot.register_next_step_handler
```

Рекурсивка:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Я бот, задающий вопросы. Готов ответить на них?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, first_question)

# Первый вопрос
def first_question(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Первый вопрос: ...? (да/нет)")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, second_question)

# Второй вопрос
def second_question(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'нет':  # Если ответ - "нет"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Всего хорошего!")
        return  # Прерываем диалог
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Второй вопрос: ...? (да/нет)")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, third_question)

# Третий вопрос
def third_question(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'нет':  # Если ответ - "нет"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Всего хорошего!")
        return  # Прерываем диалог
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Третий вопрос: ...? (да/нет)")
    # и т.д.

# Обработчик ответов на вопросы
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() in ['да', 'нет'])
def answer_handler(message):
    # Обработка ответа
    if message.text.lower() == 'да':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ на все вопросы - да!")
```

Как-то так.
Если ответ на вопрос нет - бот будет отвечать всего хорошего. если да - продолжать задавать вопросы, практикуйся и не забудь почитать доки телебота, много полезного)